# Error importing Keras layer

Tags: python, python-2.7, keras

I am having issues importing a new layer (let's call it "newlayer") for the sake of simplicity, in Keras.

I recently upgraded my Keras version using:

```
   pip install --upgrade git+git://github.com/fchollet/keras.git
```

because my older install of Keras did not have newlayer. The interesting thing I notice though is when I upgrade, Keras gets installed in the ./Python/2.7/site-packages directory. So when I cd to that directory, and import newlayer, it works fine.

However, when I am in my home directory and I import newlayer, it does not work (I get "ImportError: cannot import name newlayer").

Is there a reason for this? Maybe I installed Keras somehow to my home directory a while back and it is using that version? I tried searching my home directory for a Keras installation and it's not installed there at all. More importantly, is there a way to fix this instead of having to cd into ./Python/2.7/site-packages each time?

Comment: It is possible that you have many versions of python and pip installs one version while are running another version.

Comment: The other thing to do is to make sure that ./Python/2.7/site-packages is in your pythonpath. But if that is what is pip installs to, it must be in the python path of at least one of your python versions.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that pip is setup properly for the version of python which you are using.

You can do for example

```
curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
python2.7 get-pip.py
```

to re-install pip.

and then:

```
pip-2.7 install --upgrade git+git://github.com/fchollet/keras.git
```